# Unable to Select a Row on a List/Table Object for Desktop App Testing Using Winium for Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, winium

I'm using Winium with Python to automate a desktop application and came across a portion of my GUI I'm having issues automating.

In the process of creating a configuration, the user will have a window where they select the type of protocol to create.

[image]

The issue I'm encountering is selecting a specific row within the table, via mouse click.  Since there are multiple rows with the same protocol name, I'll want to select a row based upon both the Protocol name & Mode (i.e Modbus Slave).

Ideally, I'd want to search the table, find the desired row based upon protocol & mode, and select that row.  I've figured out how to select a row using only the Protocol name:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("WindowsForms10.SysListView32.app.0.141b42a_r9_ad1").find_element_by_id("LargeIncrement").click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name("WindowsForms10.SysListView32.app.0.141b42a_r9_ad1").find_element_by_name("Modbus").click()
```

The problem I'm having is finding a way to select a row based on both parameters.  With Web UI testing, it's usually a '/td' or '/tr' object & I can easily find the list/table within the HTML code and use its XPath to specify a row or a cell within a row.  That's not the case with my desktop app.  I've been trying to use both **Inspect Object** (Ver 7.2.0.0)...

[image]

... and **UISpy** (Ver 3.0.0.0)...

[image]
[image]

... but haven't been able to figure out how to perform this action.  With some some research and searching, I've tried some combination of the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("WindowsForms10.SysListView32.app.0.141b42a_r9_ad1").find_elements(By.NAME)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("WindowsForms10.SysListView32.app.0.141b42a_r9_ad1").find_elements(By.ID, "item")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("WindowsForms10.SysListView32.app.0.141b42a_r9_ad1")[5]
```

I did some element digging and was able to show there are 182 Xpath objects.

```
protocol_table = driver.find_element_by_class_name("WindowsForms10.SysListView32.app.0.141b42a_r9_ad1")

all_xpath_children = protocol_table.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*")
print "Length:" + str(len(all_xpath_children))
```

I'm sure there's a way to achieve this, but I'm struggling with figuring it out.  I've found very little documentation & most of the help I've found has been strictly for Java.

**Update (1) 4/24/2019**
I've also been looking at the items within the list separately hoping to find a way to perform this action.  Here is info of one of those items within the list/table:

**Inspect Object - Modbus Slave**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**UISpy - Modbus Slave**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update (2) 4/24/2019**
I found something that works somewhat.  I noticed in the screenshots above for both Inspect & UISpy, when clicking on a single item present in the table, it showed the 'LocalizedControlType' was equal to 'text'.  So I started testing different possibilities using that parameter and the success I had with XPath above.  I discovered that all 3 options below are capable of selecting the Modbus Slave line in the table:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("WindowsForms10.SysListView32.app.0.141b42a_r9_ad1").find_element_by_xpath("(//*[@LocalizedControlType='text'])[79]").click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name("WindowsForms10.SysListView32.app.0.141b42a_r9_ad1").find_element_by_xpath("(//*[@LocalizedControlType='text'])[80]").click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name("WindowsForms10.SysListView32.app.0.141b42a_r9_ad1").find_element_by_xpath("(//*[@LocalizedControlType='text'])[81]").click()
```

Selecting object 78 results in selecting Modbus Master & selecting object 82 results in selecting the next row down.  This method will work, but it would be nice to find a cleaner way of selecting a row knowing both the 'protocol' & 'mode'.

Comment: Please expand at least of of the items of your list. Yo can always iterate through a list of elements. But your screenshots do not show the elements of an item node.

Comment: @JensDibbern I've added pics of an item above (Modbus Slave).